# Why isn't the "X, at MOST n times" regex quantifier included in Java, in the "X{,n}" syntax?

Tags: java, regex, quantifiers

[Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy) tell us you can have this greedy [quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html):

```
X{n}    X, exactly n times
X{n,}   X, at least n times
X{n,m}  X, at least n but not more than m times
```

There is no mention of having `X, at MOST n times`.

---

So I made a little test:

```
boolean atMost = Pattern.matches("X{,3}", "XX");
```

I expected `atMost` to be `true`, since it's safe to assume the lower bound to be zero.
Instead, I got an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 0
X{,3}
^
```

Note it's not a thing of being *Greedy*, *Reluctant* or *Possessive*: `"X{,3}?"` and `"X{,3}+"` also don't work.

I could have used `"X{0,3}"` to achieve the pattern I'm looking for, but that's not my question.

---

**Why isn't the `X, at MOST n times` regex quantifier included in Java, in the `X{,n}` syntax?**

How is it like in other programming languages or regex "flavors"?

Comment: Because a "3 at most" quantifier `{,3}` is *exactly the same* as "between zero and three: `{0,3}`. I think it's simple as that.

Comment: I'd say because at most is finite and at least is not. It would be silly to put `"X{3,Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY}"` :)

Comment: @aliteralmind As I mentioned in the question, I'm aware of that. It's not a question of finding a matching regex, but a question on WHY wasn't `{,3}` included.

Comment: @orlandocr: aliteralmind is saying that syntax wasn't provided because it only costs 1 character to do it without that syntax, and the savings of 1 character weren't considered worth it.

Comment: @C.B. Could you expand a little? I don't get it, so what if "at most" is finite?

Comment: This is a general aspect of regex, not just Java's regex engine.

Comment: On a side note, it amazed me `boolean exactly = Pattern.matches("X{9999995465468484864312156464897946854564684654648646849645878789798789798787987846543}", "XXX");` is `false`, there was no Exception.

Comment: @orlandocr Essentially I am saying *only* looking the notation `{3,}` Implies from `3` to `Infinity`, so shouldn't `{,3}` Imply from `-Infinity` to `3`? BTW, I am aware matching negative values would be senseless.

Answer (score 3):

Its not a {n,m} issue, its a *PARSING* issue.

Left to right, { + number is all that has to be validated for a possible range
quantifier, otherwise { is literal and the parse continues.

Also, the paser wants a simple number available as the range start to compare with the
range end. It doesn't want to dither/allow simultaneous {min_default,max_default} or `{,}`

It would be too complicated at that low level to allow both.